# Guitarix amp simulator "Failed to allocate memory" jackd

Tags: 12.10, sound, jack

Has anyone any experience with [Guitarix](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Guitarix&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=01fsUNqBF-rK0QXIl4CQAg) ? I have Jack set up and working well with [Rakarrak](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Rakarrak&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=GljsUKTuD4vP0AWSiIHoCg) but it wont work with [Guitarix](https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=Guitarix&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&redir_esc=&ei=01fsUNqBF-rK0QXIl4CQAg) It tells me "could not allocate memory" dont understand why.

Am I missing something ?

Please help...

```
ulimit -a

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 47217
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 95
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 47217
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Can you add the full error?

Comment: Can you add the output of `ulimit -a`

Comment: Unfortunately I could not recreate the error message but the is still no input of output from the amp

Comment: For the memory issue, could it be that you did try to run it on another user that had limitations? (a user that did not reside in a privileged audio group?)

Comment: When you started Guitarix, did it show up in jackd? Did you connect its sink to a source? and its output to anything?

Comment: updated my answer. please look. @markkirby

Comment: Is your user in the audio and video groups ? What happens if you run guitarix as root ? `gksu guitarix` ? Do you have more then one sound card?

Answer (score 5):

This error seems due to pulseaudio and jackd running at the same time.

There are several [solutions](http://jackaudio.org/faq/pulseaudio_and_jack.html):

1. Route PulseAudio to Jack while Jack is running
2. Suspend PulseAudio while Jack is running
3. Use two different sound cards
4. Do not use pulseaudio while Jack's running (solution provided in this answer).

To test this, you can suspend pulseaudio while Jackd is running with `pasuspender -- jackd` or `pulseaudio -k`.

For a permanent solution we can give jackd real time permissions, by executing the following two commands verbatim:

1. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -p high jackd2` -- Then choose yes, you want to lock down memory and have rtprio scheduling privilege. This will add those lines automatically to config files.
2. `sudo usermod -a -G audio $USER` or `sudo adduser $USER audio` -- Add yourself to the audio usergroup
3. Finally, activate the new group by restarting your PC or user session (you can also do it in a single shell with `su $USER -c guitarix`).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a bug with either guitarix or with your hardware.

Try:

```
pulseaudio -k
jackd -d alsa & guitarix
```

After you have finished with guitarx, kill jackd

```
killall jackd
```