# Guitarix error failed to lock memory

Tags: sound, jack

Whenever I open QjackCtl start session and then open guitarix I get the following error

```
[19:20:27]  system init  ***  failed to lock memory: Cannot allocate memory
[19:20:27]  system init  ***  failed to lock memory: Cannot allocate memory
[19:20:27]  PitchTracker  ***  error creating realtime thread - tuner not started
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/237793/guitarix-amp-simulator-failed-to-allocate-memory-jackd

Answer (score 4):

Check that you are in the `audio` group by bringing up terminal and running the `groups` command.

If you do not see `audio` listed in the groups, put yourself in it by running:

```
sudo adduser $USER audio
```

I didn’t have to do any of these, I did get the error message like you did. But I forgot one important rule: turning it off and on again, or rather logging out and in again to enable the groups that were auto created when installing the software.

That being said, whether you need to add the audio group and permissions to your username, or you do not, restart the computer or log out and in to enable.

Comment: Adding my user account to the `audio` group and then logging out and in again resolved these errors for me.

Comment: I did it, and it kind of fixed some issues. Pop!_OS 20.10 seems to be having other issues.